# Is it possible to use template arguments in extern "C"' functions

Tags: c++

My requirement is to get an item from a collection using extern "c" function. The method will be as below

```
template<class _Ty,
class _Alloc = allocator<_Ty> >
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) _Ty* __cdecl GetItem(std::vector<_Alloc>* itr, int index)
{
    if (itr->size() < index)
        return NULL;

    return &itr->at(index);
}
```

While compiling im getting an error as below

```
error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
```

The use of this `extern` method is to get object data using `pinvoke` from `c#`

Comment: No, c doesn't support templates.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, that's not possible. The standard prohibits templates and their specialisations from having C linkage. Qutoing C++17 (N4659) [temp] 17/4:

> ... A template, a template explicit
>   specialization (17.7.3), and a class template partial specialization shall not have C linkage. ...

Comment: Note that if it were allowed, it still wouldn't be possible to have two different instantiations, because they would have the same (undecorated) name.

Comment: @Sjoerd - The name is not the only problem, there's calling convention to consider.  C language linkage may involve an entirely different calling convention to C++ language linkage. Personally, I think that it would be nice if there was a way of separating the two. For instance, a template whose instantiations are under the C calling convention (while still having the name mangled) could be useful in producing type-safe and efficient callbacks to C API. It's probably not possible due to ABI restrictions, but one can dream...

Answer (score 0):

Actually  no, 
 In mentioned template explicit specialization (17.7.3), and a class template partial specialization shall not have C linkage

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case where I had a header file that was included as `exter "C"` but I was able to define the template function with`extern "C++"`. e.g.,

foo.c:

```
extern "C" {
#include "bar.h"
}
```

bar. h

```
...

extern "C++" template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
static inline T1 __attribute__ ((always_inline))
f(T2 a, T3 b) {
  __builtin_unreachable();
}

extern "C++" template <>
static inline double __attribute__ ((always_inline))
f(int a, int b) {
   //
}

...
```

This worked with me in one particular situation: most but not all functions in `bar.h` needed to be included without demangling.